# VB.NET "For Each" loop not working as expected

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET 2010 / WinForms

I have a panel named "Panel1", and 3 buttons inside that panel. In the form's load event, I am creating a small red square, and want to put that red square inside each of the 3 buttons...

```
    Dim RedSquare As New Panel
    With RedSquare
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = 10
        .Height = 10
        .BackColor = Color.Red
    End With

    For Each Control As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is Button Then
            Control.Controls.Add(RedSquare)
        End If
    Next
```

But the small red square only appears inside the 1st button.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A control can only have one parent, so when you add it to the second button, it's removed from the first. If you want a red square in each button, you need to create a new one every time

```
For Each Control As Control In Panel1.Controls
    If TypeOf Control Is Button Then
        Dim RedSquare As New Panel
        With RedSquare
            .Top = 0
            .Left = 0
            .Width = 10
            .Height = 10
            .BackColor = Color.Red
        End With
        Control.Controls.Add(RedSquare)
    End If
Next
```